# How to reference a pointer and modify the address

Tags: cython

So I am working on an algorithm that there is some struct that I want to point to. A pointer to the struct gets passed around some. I am not understanding how to change the address of the pointer by passing a reference of it to a function. The problem is demonstrated in the code below:

```
cdef int there=42

cdef void point_to_there(int** a):
    a[0] = &there

cdef int *a
a[0] = 13
print a[0]
point_to_there(&a)
print a[0]
```

gives

```
13
13
```

But I would like it to give

```
13
42
```

In words, how I imagine this is as follows:

`there` is an integer defined on the heap

`point_to_there` takes a pointer to a pointer to an int, and gets the pointer to an int to point to `there` (that is a mouthful)

`cdef int *a` allocates a pointer to an int

`point_to_there(&a)` passes a reference to the pointer to an int to the function so that the pointer to an int (`a`) points to `there` which is 42.

But it doesn't. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `a[0] = 13` is very dodgy. At that stage `a` points to some arbitrary unspecified location, which you then set to 13.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea that was dodgy. I thought assigning the 0th element of an array was the same as an int-pointer. So if I change that to `cdef int here = 13` and `a = &here` then it works as intended. Did you want to make a post so that I can select it? Or should I?

Comment: I think I set `there` to 13 lol

Answer (score 0):

As DavidW pointed out in comments

```
cdef int here = 13
cdef int there = 42

cdef void point_to_there(int** a):
    a[0] = &there

cdef int *a
a[0] = &here
print a[0]
point_to_there(&a)
print a[0]
```

would the the correct usage. In the question, we were setting an arbitrary point in memory to `13` which is bad.